# unexpected output value from procedural code

Tags: javascript, dataflow

I have this piece of javascript that won't work. It is supposed to take the user input and store it into the player input variable. Then, it splits the string that is returned and splits it into an array which is then converted into an object by the function oc(). Finally, the function analyzeUserInput finds keywords in the input object and places text into the paragraph element called text accordingly. In this example if the user types in slash, poke, slice, hack, etc and the word "sword" the paragraph element is supposed to say "you did 4 damage!" but it doesn't. here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>"oh no theres a monster whatchya gonna do?"</p>
        <input id="plyrInput" type="text" />
        <button onclick="analyzeUserInput()">Try it</button>
        <p id="text"></p>
        <script>
            var plyrInput;
            var plyrInputArray;
            var plyrInputAnalysis;

            function oc() {
                plyrInputArray = plyrInput.split(' ');
                var plyrInputObj = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < plyrInputArray.length; ++i) {
                    plyrInputObj[plyrInputArray[i]] = ' ';
                }
                return plyrInputObj;
            }

            function analyzeUserInput() {
                plyrInput = document.getElementById("plyrInput").text;
                oc();
                if (plyrInputAnalysis in oc(['use', 'slash', 'hack', 'wield', 'slice', 'sever', 'dismember', 'poke', 'cripple', 'maim', 'mutilate', 'chop', 'rend']) && plyrInputAnalysis in oc(['sword'])) {
                    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You did 4 damage with your sword!";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML documents need a `<head>` element. You can use [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) to validate your code

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with why the OPs JS isn't working

Comment: @EasyBB - which is why he mentioned it in a comment, not in an answer.

Comment: Well I only state that because I know I don't post all my HTML for a JS question just a snippet

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why you call `oc` once without a parameter and once with an unused parameter. Why would you even want to call it twice? And `plyrInputAnalysis` never gets a value assigned.

Comment: best suggestion is throw out what you have and start over. Use a browser console/ developer tools to look at the most obvious errors thrown

Comment: @Oriol - Interestingly, if you run the markup through the validator, it shows only one error on a missing `title` tag in a *non-existent* `head` tag. If you add the `title` tag without the `head`, the validator doesn't complain.

Comment: Sorry for my question, but you want to show the message if in the textbox i will type 'sword' and a word in other commands? I think to have completely missed the poiint :(

Comment: @JaredFarrish True, in most cases the start and end tags of `head`, `body` and `html` can be omitted, so `<!DOCTYPE html><title>a</title>` is a valid document. But IMO it's better to include them.

Comment: @Oriol - Ironic advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var plyrInput;
        var plyrInputArray;
        var plyrInputAnalysis;

        function oc() {
            plyrInputArray = plyrInput.split(' ');
            var plyrInputObj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < plyrInputArray.length; ++i) {
                //storing these values in an object being blank is not really needed at all!
                //plyrInputObj[plyrInputArray[i]] = ' ';
                plyrInputObj[i] = plyrInputArray[i]; //acceptable or use the array itself!
            }
            return plyrInputObj;
        }

        function analyzeUserInput() {
            //plyrInput = document.getElementById("plyrInput").text;//no such property as text
            plyrInput = document.getElementById("plyrInput").value;
            //you ran this function without storing it so we can't use it
            //oc();
            var plyrAction = oc();
            //you call an undefined variable `plyrInputAnalysis`. So what are we going to do with it?
            if (plyrInputAnalysis in oc(['use', 'slash', 'hack', 'wield', 'slice', 'sever', 'dismember', 'poke', 'cripple', 'maim', 'mutilate', 'chop', 'rend']) && plyrInputAnalysis in oc(['sword'])) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You did 4 damage with your sword!";
            }
        }
```

Now for the fix:

```
        var plyrInput;
        var plyrInputArray;
        var plyrInputAnalysis;
        //added an acitonList for later usage for yourself
        var actionList = {
          'use':4,
          'slash':4,
          'hack':4,
          'wield':4,
          'slice':4,
          'sever':4,
          'dismember':4,
          'poke':4,
          'cripple':4,
          'maim':4,
          'mutilate':4,
          'chop':4,
          'rend':4
        };
        function oc() {
            plyrInputArray = plyrInput.split(' ');
            var plyrInputObj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < plyrInputArray.length; ++i) {
                plyrInputObj[i] = plyrInputArray[i];
            }
            return plyrInputObj;
        }

        function analyzeUserInput() {
            plyrInput = document.getElementById("plyrInput").value;
            var plyrAction = oc(); //cached the returned value from oc
           for(var item in plyrAction){ //looping through the plyrActions object
              if(actionList[plyrAction[item]]){ //if there is a plyrAction that matches the actionsList we'll continue.
                  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You did "+actionList[plyrAction[item]]+" damage with your sword!";
              }
           }
        }
```

Though this could seems more complicated than it needs to be I went off your original methodology, you could create a better instance of this code for an RPG game, though it would be good to look into an `IIFE` to wrap this in and minimize a lot of the code instead of multiple functions.

For instance

```
        function analyzeUserInput() {
            plyrInput = document.getElementById("plyrInput").value;
            var plyrAction = plyrInput.split(' ');
            var plyrInputObj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < plyrAction.length; ++i) {
                plyrInputObj[i] = plyrAction[i];
            }
           for(var item in plyrInputObj ){ 
              if(actionList[plyrInputObj[item]]){ 
                  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You did "+actionList[plyrInputObj[item]]+" damage with your sword!";
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: what kind of an answer is `Fix these then we will go further` ? Answer has obvious problems in it too

Comment: Yes it does ;) I am editing now, but I am explaining all the errors as I go

Comment: then it shouldn't have been applied as an answer

Comment: I wasn't go to post that long text in a comment, I was simply showing the OP that I was working on it for him. As sometimes it helps to relieve some of the stress for the OP. You should learn it instead of bickering and whining.

Comment: applaud your effort of following through...  the initial comment and broken code in answer though is not really the way it should be done. Look at it from this side...how would anyone else know that wasn't your final solution?

Comment: Well I see it here as I do ask questions myself I don't go looking for a working code, I'd rather have an explanation and for myself to work this out. How are people to learn if they don't get the explanation. So my original post itself is to show the OP what is wrong so hopefully they could fix it for themselves. this isn't StackGiveMeACode ;)